# Nothing from Property TagKey()

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I'm writing an ASP.NET custom composite control (Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeControl).

By default my control mark up renders surrounded by  tags. I know I can over ride the property TagKey to set the return as whatever tag I want from the System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterTag enum.

My question: Can I make my control render without .NET adding markup around it?

---

UPDATE (3/2/2011) Thanks Swati for your answer. I want to show how I am solving my question now. I think I will integrate some of Swati's ideas. Specifically, AddAttributestoRender(), but I'm wondering if that is needed since the CompositeControl will lack a parent markup tag to hold the attributes.

When I don't want a containing markup tag, then I override one property & two methods from CompositeControl.

```vbnet
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property TagKey() As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterTag
    Get
        ' System defaults return as HtmlTextWriterTag.Span
        Return HtmlTextWriterTag.Unknown
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Sub RenderBeginTag(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
    If Me.TagKey <> HtmlTextWriterTag.Unknown Then
        MyBase.RenderBeginTag(writer)
    End If
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub RenderEndTag(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
    If Me.TagKey <> HtmlTextWriterTag.Unknown Then
        MyBase.RenderBeginTag(writer)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s possible to get rid of the containing tag with a CompositeControl, but it’s working against the way CompositeControl likes to work (see below).

The proper way, apparently, is to set TagKey to whatever the main tag of your control actually is (a div, table, or whatever).

Then override AddAttributesToRender() to set the attributes you want on your wrapper tag.

The stuff you want inside the wrapping tags should be rendered by overriding the RenderContents() method.

CompositeControl inherits from WebControl. See a discussion of the user of TagKey and AddAttributesToRender() [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/f820d25y%28v=vs.140%29).

Someone on GeeksWithBlogs writes about a similar issue [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190904010434/http://geekswithblogs.net/mcastro/archive/2006/01/19/66393.aspx).

To just get rid of the wrapping though, see this [forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aadf87a5-1c27-48b0-b60a-986f74ed659b/removing-span-tags-in-custom-control-amp-tabindex?forum=aspservercontrols) that shows a way to override the control constructor and the RenderBeginTag and RenderEndTag methods to remove the wrapping tags.

Comment: The take-away point: its working against the way CompositeControl likes to work

I have to say big THANK YOU codeulike for pointing out AddAttributesToRender(). I've been missing that. This nugget is super helpful.

Note to other writers - learn from this post. The answer included great help & supporting links! WONDERFULLY helpful

Comment: The second link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of RenderBeginTag. The “RenderBeginTag” calls another method, the “AddAttributestoRender” method, to deal with all types of “attributes” related to only the opening tags.  The “TagKey” corresponds to the default HTML tag corresponding to the web control. If we implement our own tags within the “RenderBegintag” method, we can simply forget about the “TagKey” issue. You can do something like this..

```csharp
Public virtual void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter Writer)
{
    AddAttributestoRender(writer);
    HtmlTextWriterTag tagKey = TagKey;
    If(tagKey != HtmlTextWriterTag.Unknown)
        Writer.RenderBeginTag(tagKey);
    Else
        Writer.RenderBeginTag(this.tagName);
}
```

Comment: Very well said. I love how Stack Overflow can bring fresh views for very old questions. Thank you for taking the time to share.

Comment: What is this? Does it actually compile? It looks like a mix of C# and VB.NET (capitalised "Public", "If" and "Else").

Comment: The capitalisation of `writer` does not match the parameter `Writer`.

Comment: Shouldn't `AddAttributestoRender` be [`AddAttributesToRender`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.addattributestorender)?

Answer (score 0):

You could just override the `Render()` method, forcing it to render only the contents. Maybe something like this would do the trick:

```
public override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    RenderContents(writer);
}
```